# Restore search_path to default value in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Anyone knows how to restore search_path to default value in postgresql?
I changed its value, but now I want to use the default value again.
Any help is appreciated.

cheng

Answer (score 10):

Try with this:

```
SET search_path TO DEFAULT ;
```